# how to print a multidimension array in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, multidimensional-array, printing

i'm new to kotlin and need help printing this problem below

how do you print this code:

```
val chessBoard = mutableListOf(
        mutableListOf<String>(" ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"),
        mutableListOf<String>("1", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "),
        mutableListOf<String>("2", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W"),
        mutableListOf<String>("3", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "),
        mutableListOf<String>("4", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "),
        mutableListOf<String>("5", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "),
        mutableListOf<String>("6", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "),
        mutableListOf<String>("7", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
        mutableListOf<String>("8", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "),
    )
```

into this:

```
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
8 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
7 | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
6 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
4 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
2 | W | W | W | W | W | W | W | W |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
```

thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1):

`joinToString()` is your friend:

```
val line = "\n   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"
chessBoard.reversed().joinToString(separator = line, prefix = line) { l ->
    l.joinToString(separator = "|", postfix = "|") { " $it " }
}.also{println(it)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could do it:

```
println(
    ((chessBoard)
        .reversed()
        .map { (it + "").joinToString(if (it[0] != " ") " | " else "   ") + "\n" })
        .run { arrayOf("") + this }
        .joinToString("  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n")
)
```